# WEBM Live streaming sample links

Tags: .net, iis, video, http-live-streaming, webm

I have requirement for streaming live video using webm. I've done streaming a video file hosted on the server. But I also need to live stream videos, preferably webm video.

I found links to stream flv, mp4 ect videos, but not for webm. Can you give any sample links so that I can test that and finlaize it.

I also prefer, the best links using which I can live stream a webm video on my local IIS and ASP.net.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a ["live" webm example](https://github.com/rubu/WebMPlayer/blob/master/Samples/big_buck_bunny_live.webm) in my WebMPlayer repo - it's basically a "live" version of the Big Buck Bunny trailer.

Don't try to access it directly via the "view the full file" link from github because for somewhat reason the file is opened as "audio/webm" when you click on the link at the github page. Either clone the repo or click the link and then save the file locally.